# VBA character encoding in Access

Tags: ms-access, character-encoding, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm using Access with Slavic characters in VBA on many computers without any problems
but on my home computer, that I rarely use, I get problems as VBA (Accesss?) doesn't recognize the encoding.

I get an error at login as the code tries to add the log in entry to datumčas field . I get the error that `datum'as` is not recognized. The problem is obvious I guess, tables are keeping Central European encoding but the VBA reads it as Western encoding, something like that.

Is there a way to correct this? bypass it? My home computer Windows language is set to Slovenian with Slovenian and English installed, but I guess those settings are the same on other computers.

Comment: eh, to answer my question. I changed system locale to slovenian and now it works well. guess I was fancy at setup and went with US

Comment: If you solved your problem please add it as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

I changed the Windows system locale to Slovenian and now it works well. I guess I was fancy at setup and went with the US locale.